# Calculating matrices of an endomorphism. Is my answer correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

Consider the endomorphism $f:E\to E$ and the basis $B_E$ and $B′_E$ along with the matrices $A=M(f,B_E,B′_E)$ and $P=M(B_E,B′_E)$

Calculate the following three matrices: $B=M(f,B′_E)$, $C=M(f,B′_E,B_E)$ and $D=M(f,B_E,B′_E)$

$\textbf{My answer:}$

$\hspace{0.5cm}\bullet B = M(f, B'_E)\longrightarrow  B = P^{-1}\cdot A\cdot P$

$\hspace{0.5cm}\bullet C = M(f, B'_E, B_E)\longrightarrow C = P^{-1}\cdot A$

$\hspace{0.5cm}\bullet D = M(f, B_E, B'_E)\longrightarrow D = A$

Comment: I solved a similar problem but it was the case of a linear map $f: E \to F$ and another matrix Q to change basis was given. To obtain the matrices asked in that case I just wrote their corresponding matrix equations (e.g. $B = M(f, B'_E, B'_F)$ would be $B\cdot X'=Y'$) and then it was just a question of isolating the varibles to obtain the desired matrices.
The thing is, in this case, I'm not sure if I could follow the same process, for example: would $B=M(f,B′_E)$ be the same as $B\cdot X' = X'$?

Comment: That other problem I solved is explained in another question I made about the same topic.